# Why do Rails' default_url_options not apply when I am behind a reverse proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reverse-proxy

I find that when I run Rails 5 behind a reverse proxy, the default behaviour of `url_for` is use the host name of the upstream server, not the proxy itself.

For example, with nginx running at `front.com` and proxying requests to my upstream Rails server, which it knows as `back`, `root_url` returns `http://back/`.

If I tell nginx to pass the Host header as it proxies, `root_url` is `http://front.com`.

So far, so good. But I find using `default_url_options` in `routes.rb` (example below) does not have the power to override this. Why not? And if `default_url_options` can't override the Hostname from the request, what's the point of it?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

`default_url_options` example:

```
RoutingApp.routes.draw do
  default_url_options host: 'example.com'

  root to: 'pages#index'
end
```

(from [this gist by a Rails core developer](https://gist.github.com/pixeltrix/8278962#file-default_url_options-rb-L14))

Comment: What do you mean by "using default_url_options in routes.rb"?

Comment: @Jeremie added example code

Answer (score 0):

There are many places to set this, you set it for it to work under console, but not controller.

http://lulalala.logdown.com/posts/5835445-rails-many-default-url-options

I think you want it to work for controller/web view. Try this:

```
# production.rb
config.action_controller.default_url_options= {host: 'example.com'}
```